# Writing Unicode literal above 0xFFFF in Go?

Tags: unicode, go

How do you encode unicode code points in Go? In the example below I'm storing the hex representation of the unicode for [ace of spades](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playing_cards_in_Unicode) as `\u1F0A1` but when I print it comes out as `Ἂ1`. Why is that? If I copy and paste the ace of spades glyph it prints fine.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(" \u1F0A1")
}
```

Output

```
 Ἂ1
```

Example above in the Go playground https://play.golang.org/p/ukK57CnVuE

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lowercase `\u` is for Unicode code points from `\u0000` to `\uFFFF`. Use `\U` if you want to have code points above 0xFFFF:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(" = \U0001F0A1")
}
```

See also: [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/W1wPHEL0ym) and [the string literals section](http://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals) of the specification.

Comment: Any idea why this distinction exists?

Comment: @synful Don't know for sure, but guessing that it's for [compatibility with C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C#Universal_character_names). And C (I guess) might have this because Unicode was [planned as a 16-bit charset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#History).